# How to change the text default colour when ExpansionTile is expanded flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to change
this blue Colour when the ExpansionTile expands, unfortunately I just found that you can easily change the Background Colour of the whole header with this collapsedBackgroundColor: , but is there also a way to change the texts background colour?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `textColor` and `iconColor` and its corresponding collapsed variants.

```dart
          child: ExpansionTile(
            textColor: Colors.amber,
            iconColor: Colors.amber,
            collapsedTextColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
            collapsedIconColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
```

See the colors :
[image: Code]

The `ExpansionTile` collapsed

[image: Collapsed]

And expanded

[image: expanded]

Comment: Is that possible in the newest update? Have the feeling that it isn't defined anymore. Get the error: The named parameter 'textColor & collapsedTextColor' isn't defined.

Comment: Well at least for `ExpansionTile` on the stable channel(2.2.0) this works.

Comment: Im terribly lost didn't update my flutter, seems as it was added later, works obviously now, thx

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
class MyExpansionTile extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ExpansionTile(
            title: Text(
              'Example',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
            ),
            collapsedTextColor: Colors.green,
            textColor: Colors.blue
          );
      }
  }
```

for more details [Collapsed Text Color](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile/collapsedTextColor.html)

Comment: get the error error: "The named parameter 'collapsedTextColor' isn't defined. "

Comment: with your added part, or just the initial TextTile part?

Comment: Im terribly lost didn't update my flutter, seems as it was added later, works obviously now, thx

Comment: @Nikita No Problem

Answer (score 1):

create ThemeData and  define  expansionTileTheme in it.  You can also create different themes for dark and light modes

```
final appTheme = ThemeData(
        colorScheme:ColorScheme(
          //....
              ),
      expansionTileTheme:ExpansionTileThemeData(
        textColor: Colors.grey,
        iconColor: Colors.grey
      ),// This Part
      cardColor: Colors.grey[900],
      appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(
        color: Colors.lightBlueAccent[500],
        foregroundColor: Colors.white70
      ),
      scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.black,
      fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
    );
```

add it to materialApp

```
MaterialApp(
      navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
      scaffoldMessengerKey: scaffoldMessengerKey,
      theme: appTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,
      themeMode:  brightness == null
          ? ThemeMode.system
          : brightness == Brightness.dark
              ? ThemeMode.dark
              : ThemeMode.light,
    );
```